# JSON file displaying with PHP and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I've been trying to display a json file from a database on Phpmyadmin, in vain. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Heres my code :

json.php

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $data=array();
    $q=mysqli_query($con, "select * from mesures");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
     $data[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="measureController as measureCtrl" style="margin-top:170px; border:0">
    <h1>ok</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="record in measureCtrl.records" class="row">
        {{record.test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

mesure-controller.js

```
angular.module('mesure', [])

.controller('measureController', ['$scope', 'recordService',
        function($scope, recordService) {

        this.records = new Object();


        function getData(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
            recordService.getAll(function(callback){
                if (callback != null){
                    //location.reload();
                    //console.log(callback);
                    this.records = callback;
                    return callback;
                }
            });

        })
        }
        this.records = getData();

        //console.log(this.records);
}]);
```

recordService.js

```
angular.module('recordService', []).factory('recordService', ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {

    var RecordService = {};

    var recordList = new Array();

    return {
        getAll : function (callback) {
            $(document).ready(function()
             {
                 var url="http://localhost/Effienergy/Effi-Prove/www/database/json.php";
                 $.getJSON(url,function(result){
                     //console.log(result);
                     $.each(result, function(i, field){
                         var record =
                         {
                            "test" : field.test,
                            "test2" : field.test2,
                         };
                         recordList.push(record);
                         //console.log(record)
                     });
                 }).done(function(){callback(recordList)});
             });
        },

        get : function (id) {
            for (record in this.recordList) {
                if ((this.recordList[record]).id == id) {
                    return (this.recordList[record]);
                }
            }
            return null;
        },

        add : function (record) {
            this.recordList.push(record);
        }



//        //5 secondes après le chargement de la page, la valeur d'une propriété change dans le service.
//        //La view est mise à jour automatiquement
//        $timeout(function() {
//            userData.userName = "NATNAT";
//        }, 5000);


    };

}]);
```

The Json seems valid when I check it in the developer console, so I assume it has something to do with the scope I'm trying to do..

here's my json : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zckUN.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Try to add these lines : header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: @Ramkee Thing is that I don't get any particular error in the console. My <div> is just empty. I tried the header, didn't fix unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see my comment didnt post again. let me try for 3rd time. $.getJson is not Angular and changes will not be visible to Angular. please replace with $http({url:url}).then(functiom(rs){console.log(rs)},functiom(err){ console.log(err)})
the dissapearing array could be caching. in chrome dev tools pls disable caching under the network tab

**Edit:** ok looking at your pastebin, the $http isn't returning the results:

Your service should look like this:

```
angular.module('recordService', []).factory('recordService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var recordService = [];
    recordService.getAll = function (callback) {
        var url = "http://localhost/Effienergy/Effi-Prove/www/database/json.php";
        $http({url: url}).then(function (rs) {
            callback(rs.data);
            console.log(rs)

        }, function (err) {

            console.log(err)
        })

    }
    return recordService;
}]);
```

And then in your controller keep it simple:

```
angular.module('mesure', [])

.controller('measureController', function($scope, recordService) {

        $scope.records = [];       
        recordService.getAll(function(rs) {
            $scope.records = rs;
            console.log(rs);
        });
}]);
```

Your index looks fine

```
<div ng-controller="measureController as measureCtrl" style="margin-top:170px; border:0">
    <h1>ok</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="record in measureCtrl.records" class="row">
        {{record.test}} - {{record.test2}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer. I feel like i'm close, I can see the object thanks to console.log(rs). But I'm not quite sure how to push it into my array now :/ 

Here's my code at the moment :

http://pastebin.com/kSeRvqGy

Comment: Well it depends on the format of the JSON. Can u post that pls

Comment: Here's how my JSON displays in the network tab : https://imgur.com/55mLf3b . Not sure if thats what you want to see, you can also check my json.php file in my original post

Comment: Oh ok yes i saw that,  but thats test data. Before we go further what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I want to display the values of my datas on my index page through the scope ( {{record.test}} ), maybe order them in a table later, but first I'd would be nice if I could actually see them.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my previous post. I can see the object thanks to console.log(rs) but only in the console. Not on my actual page yet

Comment: Hm.. The console.log($scope.records) returns 'undefined' in the console, any idea .. :/ ?

Comment: Hi yes your service didn't return the promise. return recordService;
And because it's a promise we should use then() to assign the returned value in your controller. Please see my edit

Comment: Hey, it looks like the return might be at the wrong place. It says : Unexpected token return. + I got a [$injector:modulerr] error. I will try to check the issue. But for now I need a little break ^^.

Comment: apologies I didn't give your service much attention and just hacked on top of your code, I standardized it now, also easier to read,.should work fine

Comment: Now im struggling with this issue : Failed to instantiate module EffiProve due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=r...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/Effienergy/Effi-Prove/www/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://localhost/Effienergy/Effi-Prove/www/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js:40:134

I did my researches, most of the time its due to NgRoute, but I've already linked it before, so I don't know

Comment: hi yes that is a ngRoute module error, I did change the name of that module, but since I don't know what your route provider looks like I could have made a mistake there. just change the name back to 'recordService'

Comment: Ah yeah indeed, didn't notice thanks. Though now i got a 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' error. Pretty sure its in the controller where the function(rs) isnt recognized

Comment: Hi sorry i realize now you can't pass a promise like that from a service, we need to use the callback function so that the service can run the assignment once the query is finised. So just remove then from the service call and add that same function into getAll. Then in the service just add callback(rs); I will update the code for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it fixed it. I also had to replace "record in measureCtrl.records" to "record in records" in my html for some reason and it finally displays. Now i see clearly how the whole data-scope system is working. Thanks you again, highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Please try and change this line

```
$data [] = $row;
```

To

```
array_push ($data,$row);
```

Comment: Hello, didnt fix unfortunately. Thanks for trying to help though.

Another strange thing is that when I inspect the element, it looks like I do not have access to ng -repeat . I just see " <- Ngrepeat : record in mesureCtrl.records -> . I do not know if this is normal

Comment: Please i forgot to mention. The document.ready blocks do not belong in Amgular. Please remove all of them. Also this.records need to be $scope.records in the controller

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I did what you said but that didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Unbelievable, I saw my array by spamming refresh. Then I refreshed again and it disappeared... I don't get it

Comment: If you get a chance please use $http and let us know the result, You would also need to inject it into recordService